# Updating nginx config while attempting to invert directory structure

Tags: laravel, nginx, fastcgi, vhosts, nginx-location

I am trying to flip the directory structure of a PHP app that contains a Laravel sub-app that currently has the following directory structure:

```
/-
    /directory1-
        script1.php
    /laravel-
        /public-
            /css-
                some-file.css
    ... other laravel files ...
```

What I'm trying to do is now flip the "legacy" code in the parent directory into the Laravel application so that the directory structure now looks like this:

```
/-
    /legacy-
        /directory1-
            script1.php
    /public-
        /css-
            some-file.css
    ... other laravel files ...
```

I'm running into difficulty with the nginx configuration, I am able to successfully run the `/legacy` scripts and load the static public files in Laravel (such as some-file.css above), but none of my Laravel routes are working correctly. This is complicated by the fact that I don't want any of the legacy paths to change (I still want / to go to the now /legacy/index.php) and I want the Laravel app to be prefixed by /laravel (since I have front-end code calling an API at /laravel/api/v1 that I don't want to update just yet).

Here's what I have for the nginx config for the two different locations:

```
server {
    # ...
    root /var/www/legacy;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /laravel {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        rewrite ^/laravel/public/(.*) /../public/$1;
        try_files $uri /../public/index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

The error I am getting from nginx is: `FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream`, which I think is talking about the SCRIPT_FILENAME FastCGI param. I tried adding a named location for this, similar to the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37189590/697370):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string @laravel;
}

location @laravel {
    fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/public/index.php?$query_string;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

But this has the same effect. If someone has a solution that will be able to route requests from both `/laravel/api/v1/.*` and `/api/v1/.*` to the Laravel app that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the parent directory is `www`, I think the below config (from [this post](https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-php-in-subdirectory)) will work:

```
server {
    # ...
    root /var/www/legacy;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /laravel {
        alias /var/www/public;

        try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel;

        location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
         }
    }

    location @laravel {
         rewrite /laravel/(.*)$ /laravel/index.php?/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
    }
}
```

To deal with duplicate `fastcgi_*` declarations, you can either declare them in the `server` block or copy them in a file and include it, [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-and-implementing-fastcgi-proxying-in-nginx#breaking-out-fastcgi-configuration) explains how inheritance in Nginx works.

Comment: I got this to work, thanks. The `alias` inside the laravel location and the sub-location fastcgi declaration I think are the tricks I was missing.